# SharePoint 2010 - Targetting propertyStoreDB to a specific content source

Tags: search, crawling, enterprise-search

We have two propertyStore DBs in our SharePoint 2010 environment, is it possible to configure in such a way that a specific propertyStore DB is used for the provided(specific set of) content sources(like host distribution rule is used to target the crawl DB)?

and a specific query component is assigned to a specific propertyStore DB?

Also, help me with other recommendations on propertyStore DB.

Comment: any help on this..?